# Slow Neo4j Query. Takes 4312 milliseconds?

Tags: neo4j

I get results with my database, but its way to slow.

The entire node path hangs off of VBI_ded42b6667f, so I would think it should be fast.

The dataset I'm using is only 20MB so I'm not understanding why this is so slow. In my neo4jproperties file, I have node_keys_indexable set to the V, OI, VI, etc nodes.

Can anyone give me pointers on how to make this query only take 150 ms ?

```
MATCH (VB_dbddd5e6731:VI)<-[:INS]-(VBI_ded42b6667f:V { name:'axpl' } ),
( non_dom:OI)<-[:AG]-(VB_dbddd5e6731 ), 
( OI_64cc557459:OI { u:'hello_ry' })<-[:PA]-(VB_dbddd5e6731 ),
(VB_3901242e244:VI)<-[:INS]-(VBI_ded42b6667f),
( p1ou:OI)<-[:AG]-(VB_3901242e244 ),
( p2ou:OI)<-[:AG]-(VB_3901242e244 ),
( OI_49067f7680:OI)<-[:PA]-(VB_3901242e244 ),
( non_dom:OI)<-[:PA]-(VB_3901242e244 )
RETURN OI_49067f7680,VB_dbddd5e6731
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the `node_keys_indexable` property does, but you should make sure you have an index on the `name` property for the `V` label and the `u` property for the `OI` label.  You create that in Cypher like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :V(name)
CREATE INDEX ON :OI(u)
```

If that doesn't help, put `PROFILE` at the start of your query in Neo4j's web console to get output which shows you what parts of your query are slow.

On another note: to make your query more readable, I would suggest starting with the anchor nodes (the ones where you're filtering based on a property's value).  Also I would organize your `MATCH` so that it flows out from the anchor node as much as possible.  Like this:

```
MATCH
  (OI_64cc557459:OI { u:'hello_ry' })<-[:PA]-(VB_dbddd5e6731:VI)
  <-[:INS]-(VBI_ded42b6667f:V { name:'axpl' } )-[:INS]->(VB_3901242e244:VI),

  (VB_dbddd5e6731)-[:AG]->(non_dom:OI)

  (VB_3901242e244)-[:AG]->(p1ou:OI)
  (VB_3901242e244)-[:AG]->(p2ou:OI)
  (VB_3901242e244)-[:PA]->(OI_49067f7680:OI)
  (VB_3901242e244)-[:PA]->(non_dom)

RETURN
  OI_49067f7680,
  VB_dbddd5e6731
```

Also, maybe your query is being generated dynamically, but I find it really hard to understand the domain because of all the acronyms.  That may not be a problem if you're working by yourself, but if you get any help it can make things confusing.  Neo4j works best (I think) when you use descriptive labels and relationship types.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the suggestions. I dont understand why i need an index on everything with only 329 nodes/edges in Neo4j.  I can only imagine the performance with millions of nodes. I added the indexes but  the query is still ~3000ms. I cant believe I have to start examing query plans for a query of a few hundred nodes (no other database requires that)

Comment: I'm with Brian. I can't really understand what's going here because of all the machine-like names. 3 seconds is way too long for any query on a dataset your size. The overwhelming odds are is the way you're writing the query is making Neo4j do exponentially more work than it should be.

Comment: The indexes won't help much if you're talking about hundreds of nodes, so I'm not sure why it's slow.  How many relationships do you have?  Also, have you run a `PROFILE`?

Comment: Yes, the cypher is auto-generated. I can't change the names. Thanks for your help though !  I'm working on the query.